# Problems with PostgreSQL after changing from SQLite

Tags: python, python-3.x, database, postgresql, sqlite

I was writing a python program and used SQLite there. But after deploying it, understood that I should use PostgreSQL in order to have database globally.

```
import os
import import psycopg2

DB_Host = os.environ['DB_Host']
DB_Database = os.environ['DB_Database']
DB_User = os.environ['DB_User']
DB_Port = os.environ['DB_Port']
DB_Password = os.environ['DB_Password']

connection = psycopg2.connect(database = DB_Database, user = DB_User, password = DB_Password, host = DB_Host, port = DB_Port)
```

That is how I connected to my database.

Now, in the following code, I tried to create a table and insert something to it, but that functions doesn't work.

```
def sql_table(connection):
    cur = connection.cursor()
    cur.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tasks(id integer PRIMARY KEY, user_id integer, task text)")
    connection.commit()
    cur.close()

def sql_insert(connection, user_id, new_task):
    cur = connection.cursor()
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO tasks(user_id, task) VALUES(%s, %s)", (user_id, new_task, ))
    connection.commit()
    cur.close()
```

Where can be the mistake?

Comment: You haven't said what went wrong.

Comment: Well, when functions sql_table and sql_insert are not working.

Comment: "Not working" does not tell us anything. **What happens**? Do you get an error? Which? How do you call them?

Comment: I pushed it to Heroku when I call that functions, they don't respond. But before that, when I used SQLite, everything worked.

Answer (score 1):

One thing I can see right away is that the `INSERT` must fail because it does not insert `id`. So a `NULL` value will be assigned to that column. But the column is a `PRIMARY KEY`, hence `NOT NULL`, so that will cause an error.

If you want the `id` to be auto-generated, use

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tasks (
   id integer GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
   user_id integer,
   task text
)
```

or on older versions

```
...
   id serial PRIMARY KEY
...
```

Comment: I have been too terse, sorry. I have extended the answer to clarify that.